# Android: How to make a custom title for a TabActivity

Tags: android, title

I want to give my TabActivity a custom title.But the following Codes don't work. What's wrong in the Code? And how can i make a custom title for a TabActivity? Thank you!

```
public class ShowExam_TabAct extends TabActivity {
public static boolean customTitleSupported = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

    customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    if (customTitleSupported) {
         getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                    R.layout.title);
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_title);
        title.setText("new title!");
    }

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Mars")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, List1.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Earth")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, List2.class)));

}
}
```

Comment: What is the error comes out ?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if(customTitleSupported){
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_title);
        title.setText("new title!");
        ....
}
```